# mongodb with groupby with multi filed count

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

MongoDB, I have a collection like this

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d02308e129aab55b3df814a"),
    "title" : "fgdfg",
    "user_id" : "5bc5dc03f6d24d29077dd362",
    "click" : false,
    "type_id" : "5d00a304430fee3160ac881f",
    "type" : "user_notification",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d02308e129aab55b3df8149"),
    "title" : "fgdfg",
    "user_id" : "5bc5dc03f6d24d29077dd362",
    "click" : true,
    "type_id" : "5d00a304430fee3160ac881f",
    "type" : "user_notification",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d02308e129aab55b3df8148"),
    "title" : "fgdfg",
    "user_id" : "5bc5dc03f6d24d29077dd362",
    "click" : true,
    "type_id" : "5d00a304430fee3160ac881f",
    "type" : "user_notification",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I want with the "type_id" group by query and same query I want how many "click" field true and false of type_id.

Conclusion: I want total type_id count and total "click" field "true" count in each type id in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MongoDB Group,

```
let query = [{
    $group: {
        _id: "$type_id",
        "true": { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$click', true] }, 1, 0] } },
        "false": { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$click', false] }, 1, 0] } },

    },
}, {
    $addFields: {
        "addition": { $add: ["$true", "$false"] }
    }
}]
```

Comment: I have get below result
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Data found",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "5d00a304430fee3160ac881f",
            "true": 1,
            "false": 2
        }
    ]
}

Click true and false count is working perfect.
But i can't get total "type_id" record

Comment: let query = [{
        $group: {
            _id: "$type_id",
            "true": { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$click', true] }, 1, 0] } },
            "false": { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$click', false] }, 1, 0] } },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }]
I have added "count: { $sum: 1 }" and it's working